# Insert all data from one database to another looping through each table

Tags: sql, database, dynamic, insert

I am looking for a script to insert data from all tables into another database with the exact same schema. The tables have already been created, DatabaseA is empty and databaseB has all the data.

The generate script method works but inserting each record will take far too long.
I need a code which will iterate through each table, construct a dynamic insert into (column!, columnB etc) with identity insert on.

end result will mean the data in both databases is totally synchronized. SOMTHING LIKE THIS BELOW

```
declare @Table varchar(50)= 'Years'


SELECT 'INSERT INTO ' + @Table +
STUFF ((
    SELECT ', [' + name + ']'
    FROM syscolumns
    WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('Years') AND
        name <> 'me'
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 


SELECT 'SELECT ' +
STUFF ((
    SELECT ', [' + name + ']'
    FROM syscolumns
    WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('Years') AND
        name <> 'me'
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') +
' FROM '+ @Table
```

Comment: you can create  dblink between databases , and simple use insert into tablename select * from tablename@otherdblink

Comment: but it's not best practies

Comment: yes except when you use identity_insert on your have to specify all the columns. Also there are 400 + tables, so will still need something dynamic i.e cursor/loop

Comment: Don't forget you'll need to do inserts in an order than respects FKs. I would suggest backing up the source database and restoring that backup into the destination: avoids lots of complexity.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using: metadata functions (list of tables, lists of columns, ...) is not standard.

Comment: correct, I will be disabling all the FK contraints when doing this insert. luckly this database was constructed poorly so there aren't many contraints.